# Vue submit input hidden

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to pass two Id's alongside a users input. I'm putting those Id's in a hidden input. I already understand that the v-model does not work with hidden inputs. That's why my hidden input looks like this

```
<input type="hidden" ref="property_id" :name="form.property_id"  :value="property_id"><
```

The following is my full block of code:

```
<template>
    <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit()">
       <div v-for="(property, propIndex) in properties" :key="propIndex">
           {{ property.name }}
          <div v-for="(house_type, typeIndex) in property.house_type.data" :key="typeIndex">
              {{ house_type.type }}<br>
              <input type="text" v-model="rent[propIndex][typeIndex]">Rent<br>
              <input type="text" v-model="house_quantity[propIndex][typeIndex]">How many<br>
              <input type="hidden" ref="property_id" :name="form.property_id"  :value="property_id"><br>
              <input type="hidden" ref="house_type_id" :name="form.house_type"  :value="house_type.type"><br>
          </div>
          <br>
       </div>
          <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
data() {
    return {
            rent:[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
            house_quantity:[{}, {}, {},{}, {}, {},{}, {}, {}],
            form:{
                property_id: [],
                house_type: [],
            }
           

    }
},
}
</script>
```

How do I get the values of the hidden inputs so that I can submit them alongside the rest of the data.

```
methods: {
        async submit(){
            this.form.rent = this.rent
            this.form.house_quantity = this.house_quantity
            await axios.post('/api/landlord/set/up/store/part/3', this.form)
        }
  },
```

Comment: Your use of `:value` is the correct approach. `:value="property_id"` in the first input is undeclared. Perhaps it's supposed to be `:value="form.property_id"` or `:value="property.id"`?

Comment: It should be `property.id` which I'm getting from `v-for="(property, propIndex) in properties"`. I want to be able to submit those hidden inputs. With v-model if it's  `<input type="text" v-model="rent">Rent</input>` then I can access it with `data() {return {rent:[]}` and then submit it with `await axios.post('/api/landlord/set/up/store/part/3', this.rent)`.  How do I do the same with input hidden that has no v-model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you can use `v-bind` to bring the values to the input and make a method or computed property that gets the values back to `this.form.property_id` and `this.form.house_type` when input `@blur` or `@change`, for example.

This would update data back even without having the `v-model` interactivity you need.